# How to insert file lines into table in lua

Tags: lua, luvit

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with lua and its going well so far, but I'm having a couple problems with the IO portion of lua.
I'm trying to read a large list.txt file in lua and inserting each line into a table, but so far all of my attempts didn't work.
Any advice?

Attempt #1 spits out nil:

```
local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
    file:close()
    return content
end
local fileContent = read_file("list.txt")

local vga_files = {}
table.insert(vga_files, fileContent)
```

Comment: `for line in io.lines("list.txt") do table.insert(vga_files, line) end`

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your error running your code. Your code is valid, and is likely doing what you asked it to do.

here you tell the `read_file` function to return `nil`:

```lua
if not file then return nil end
```

So if the `file` is not found you will get `nil`. A good step in debugging would be to add a print in the body of this if statement and see if it is getting entered.

When you call `read_file`:

```
local fileContent = read_file("list.txt")
```

you pass in only a file name, this means lua will look for that where ever the code is being executed, and this location maybe different from what you expect.

I validated your code works by pointing the read at itself, and printing the result.

```
local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
    file:close()
    return content
end

print(read_file("so_io_read_test.lua"))
```

---

Additionally to get the lines you should really used `io.lines` which creates an iterator that you can use in a for loop.

```
local vga_files = {}
for line in io.lines("list.txt") do 
    table.insert(vga_files, line)
end
```

Or alternatively you can read the file and then split the lines using gmatch.

```
local contents = read_file("so_io_read_test.lua")
for line in contents:gmatch("([^\n]+)") do
  table.insert(vga_files, line)
end
```